# Configuring OpenStack to have mutiple servers running

Tags: mongodb, virtualbox, vagrant, openstack

I am really new to the virtualization world and i recently came across OpenStack and i thought i could use it to build a dev environment with multiple servers like mongodb, zend server, rabbitmq, mysql, MariaDB etc.. I just read that the latest version called Havana is released yesterday 10/17/2013.

Are there any tutorials on how to go about installing servers on openstack using virtual box or vagrant.?

I would like to make an image of the dev setup and finally have multiple nodes running..

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please note that this is a website about programming problems only, so it is off-topic here. But your question could be more on-topic in our sister-communities http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com

Comment: You need to read more about how OpenStack works (http://www.openstack.org/software/start/). Also, these types of questions aren't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: you might be more interested in docker.io for this sort of thing.